# Will I likely have trouble flying to Japan after a stay in China as a US Citizen?

Tags: japan, us-citizens, china, visa-free-entry, denial-of-entry

I'm going to China for work (a conference) for about a week, and thought it may be nice to visit my friend in Japan for 2-3 days or so on the way back, especially with the reduced flight costs compared to flying to Japan from the US at a later time. I've found a few references on difficulties flying *to* China *from* Japan in certain circumstances (e.g. [the site referenced in this question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/122843/do-i-need-a-china-visa-when-i-fly-from-japan-to-china-as-a-u-s-citizen)), but not the other way. I'm concerned because I've heard about these issues from Japan->China as well as knowing Chinese nationals require a Visa to enter Japan, and while that doesn't apply to me, I don't know if there will be mixups at the airport because of that state of affairs, or if there's special procedure/law I'm not aware of.

This would all be pre-planned, no open ended tickets, so USA->China (~1 week)->Japan (a few days)->USA would all be pre-planned if I did this. Are there any known difficulties with this sort of travel plan? I'd prefer not to be stuck in China figuring out how to get tickets back to the US ASAP because I can't do my preplanned flight path.

Comment: What is the issue you see in the linked question? The only problematic thing that I can see there is about *getting a visa to China in Japan if you are not a Japanese citizen/resident*, not travelling between the countries. And it is a fairly usual restriction, you just take care of getting the visas from the USA and all is set. And of course, at your arrival of Japan the admission requirements will depend of your citizenship (i.e. your passport), not from where the plane did come from.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you will not have any issues at all doing this.  I have personally taken this exact trip multiple times without any issues.  The immigration staff in Japan will know where you flew in from (it's on the card you fill out), but will not care about the fact you've come from China.

(Of course, this presumes that there are no other reasons for you to have issues going through immigration in Japan - such as not having the correct documentation/etc)